# Can kafka capture change in views of a database

Tags: database, apache-kafka, streaming

Is it possible for kafka streaming to capture the change in database view? I have a view in database with columns form several tables. So will kafka detect the data change in view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Out of the box, no, Kafka doesn't interact with any database.

If you can query a view using JDBC periodically, though, then you can use the [apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect) JDBC Source Connector to get those same rows of data as Kafka records.

Or you can use a CDC product such as [debezium](/questions/tagged/debezium) to stream out all individual relevant tables the view uses, and join them within KStreams/KSQL to recreate the entire materialized view table, but backed by a stream

Comment: Great answer! One thing to add is that Debezium cannot capture changes to the contents of DB views themselves.

Comment: Added "individual tables" for clarification